# Sitecore: Base a field on other fields

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I was wondering if it was possible in sitecore to base a field off of two other fields for vice versa.

For instance, I have a template with the following fields:

```
FullName
FirstName
LastName
```

I want to know if there is any mechanism in sitecore that allows me to make FullName equivalent to concatenating FirstName and LastName with a space in between.

Is there? If there is, can I go the other way? (For instance, accept FullName as $name and split on a space to produce FirstName and LastName)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I way I can think of doing something like this is by creating a custom composite field.

[Creating a Composite Custom Field](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/API/Creating%20a%20Composite%20Custom%20Field.aspx)

For the revers you would need to look at creating a custom standard value token.

[Add Custom Standard Values Tokens in the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/01/Add-Custom-Standard-Values-Tokens-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx)